# PHP – Find common string in value in multiple arrays and combine output

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to avoid a database by using arrays. I don't know if it's the right approach though, since I'm not so fluent in PHP.

Would this MySQL scenario be possible with arrays:

"Select all sub-arrays which age-value contain the string '23' (age) and combine their label-key into a new array".

```
$bears = array(
            array(label => "Parent", ages => "23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33"),
            array(label=>"Adult", ages => "19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29"),
            array(label => "Teenager", ages => "14 15 16 17 18")
)

$klingons = array(
            array(label => "Some", ages => "20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28"),
            array(label => "Something", ages => "19 20 21 22 23"),
            array(label => "Dark side", ages => "14 15 16 17 18")
)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Whether this is the right approach vs a database just depends on the size of your data, how often it changes and how complex the querying will be. If you really only have 2 arrays with 3 items each, then a database is likely overkill. If you have multiple categories with thousands of items, a database will likely be faster to perform queries against. With arrays you will likely be filtering the data which is essentially the same as querying against a table with no indexes performing a less optimized "table scan" meaning looking at every "row" to compare.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, @Jonathan! It's actually just 5 arrays (like $bear, $clingons) with 3 arrays in each of them. So like you said, I'll not use a database but try arrays.

Comment: I'd suggest using arrays to store your sets of ages instead of strings, if possible. If you need to search for 8 at some point, for example, you'll match strings with 18 and 28 as well, unless you use a regex for matching. It may not be an issue for your data, but `in_array` seems more straightforward than `preg_match`.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I thought of that too, but unfortunately my skillset is limited, so I used strings instead of another set of arrays. I'd prefer to use arrays though.  : /

Comment: It's unclear what your question. Are you just asking if your approach is possible? Of course, it's just a matter of programming. If you're asking *how* to code it, that's off-topic. [so] expects you to try to solve the problem yourself, and post code if you can't get it working.

Comment: Just change `"20 21..."` to `[20, 21, ...]`. Voila! you have an array.

Comment: You already seem to understand the notion of nested arrays, since both your variables contain them. Another level of nesting is the same concept.

Comment: Come on @Barmar. Are you kidding me or are you just bored? I'm actually trying to solve the problem myself, obviously. Otherwise I would not have asked how to approach it or in which direction I should look. Could be that there's a PHP-function I don't know yet or some other technique. And yes, I'm reading the PHP-manual. I am asking for advice.

Comment: Use a `foreach()` loop to loop over the array. Use `in_array()` to tell if the number is in the `ages` array. If it is, add the `label` value to the result array.

Comment: If you tried to solve it, show what you came up with. We don't expect it to work, or you wouldn't be here. But you don't learn anything by having us show you the final code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it via iteration like this:

```
$bears = array(
    array('label' => "Parent", 'ages' => "23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33"),
    array('label' =>"Adult", 'ages' => "19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29"),
    array('label' => "Teenager", 'ages' => "14 15 16 17 18")
);

$newArray = array();

foreach($bears as $bear)
{
    if(strpos($bear['ages'], '23') !== false)
            $newArray[] = $bear['label'];
}

echo("Results:\n");
var_dump($newArray);
```

Note you have to encapsulate "label" in quotes in your arrays as they are strings.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help! I managed to combine in_array and your suggestion. Thanks!